# Responive Text and Miminum size - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, responsive

I want to make my app responsive that looks good on all screens.

What should be the size of text,using constant values like `16` for text good?

what values should i use for paddings?:

```
padding:EdgeInsets.all(24)
```

or

```
padding:EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/50)
```

What should be the minimum width and height of my app and what should be displayed if the screen is smaller than that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Responsiveness you can leverage use of `MediaQuery`.

```
height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
width =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

And based on the `height` and `width` you can set other values such as `height`, `width` of the widgets

---

Further you can take aid of flutter's `Material design` Specs:

For `Text` you can use like:

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium
```

For different usecases you can use different default textstyles defined by `Material design`.

| NAME | SIZE | WEIGHT | SPACING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| displayLarge | regular | 57.0 | 0 |
| displayMedium | regular | 45.0 | 0 |
| displaySmall | regular | 36.0 | 0 |
| headlineLarge | regular | 32.0 | 0 |
| headlineMedium | regular | 28.0 | 0 |
| headlineSmall | regular | 24.0 | 0 |
| titleLarge | medium | 22.0 | 0 |
| titleMedium | medium | 16.0 | 0.15 |
| titleSmall | medium | 14.0 | 0.1 |
| labelLarge | medium | 14.0 | 0.1 |
| labelMedium | medium | 12.0 | 0.5 |
| labelSmall | medium | 11.0 | 0.5 |
| bodyLarge | regular | 16.0 | 0.15 |
| bodyMedium | regular | 14.0 | 0.25 |
| bodySmall | regular | 12.0 | 0.4 |

And for the padding it is better to use a constant value like `16`

```
padding:EdgeInsets.all(16)
```

---

**Caution:!!!!**

```
padding:EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) // Never use this , This is not the good usecase and should never be used. Your content would be never visible
```

Comment: using `Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium` i am not able to change other properties of textStyle. how can i do it?

Comment: Use .copyWith()

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil package ,that will handle adaptive font size for different screens

A flutter plugin for adapting screen and font size.Let your UI display a reasonable layout on different screen sizes!

Go through the documentation for learn more.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Set the fit size (Find your UI design, look at the dimensions of the device screen and fill it in,unit in dp)
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context , child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'First Method',
          // You can use the library anywhere in the app even in theme
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: Typography.englishLike2018.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.sp),
          ),
          home: child,
        );
      },
      child: const HomePage(title: 'First Method'),
    );
  }
}
```